# Using public DNS/IP from within Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, dns

Is there any way to make a service running within Amazon EC2 accessible by its public DNS or IP from "within" EC2. More specifically, I have a Java server and I would like to establish a Socket connection to it by specifying its public DNS/IP from a client running within EC2 as well. I know I can use the private DNS/IP.

The code on the client would be something simple such as:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(PUBLIC-DNS,PORT);
```

Comment: Yes, but you probably don't want to.  You will pay transport charges for the data since it leaves your EC2 deployment and comes back again via the public IP.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you need to go that way, that will work + you need to add that port number to firewall allowed list - outboud connection and add that port number to EC2 security group outbound connection.